# Different property files when depend on a library

Tags: java, maven

I have two different projects, A and B. Both projects load their own properties with:

```
new PropertiesConfiguration("application.properties")
```

Each `application.properties` is located in the Maven resource root directory.

When I execute Project B alone, all properties are loaded correctly.

Project A depends on Project B. When I execute Project A, the property class of Project B cannot load the correct properties, because the properties of Project A are loaded.

How can each Project load the correct properties even if they are included as a dependency. I have to specify to load the resources in different contexts, but I don't know how.

My maven settings for resources:

```xml
<resource>
  <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
<resource>
  <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

Comment: why don't you give different name to these properties file?

Comment: i don't want to depend if somebody who uses project B knows how I name my ressources. project B should independently load its own resources. another example would be a log4j.xml which has the same name in project a and project b

Comment: @KaiSchlegel Log4J configuration is a bad example. Typically you want there to be only one `log4j.xml` per project, which will control logging for all dependencies. The different `Logger` names allow fine tuning of log settings for different packages. I agree with jolivier that you should name the files differently.

Comment: i thought there might be a setting in maven to set the classpath context. so every resource should be taken from the own directory. I'm not really convinced by the renaming. I most cases i don't know the resource name of my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some specific packages for Project B like

```
com.company.packageB
```

So put your `application.properties` in

```
src/main/resources/com/company/packageB/application.properties
```

And same for the Project A

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all application.properties files like this

```
    for (Enumeration<URL> urls = ClassLoader.getSystemResources("application.properties"); urls.hasMoreElements();) {
        URL url = urls.nextElement();
    }
```

Depending on your application you have to make a choice how to proceed if multiple property files are found. I hope this helps.